# How to set the date on JDatePicker's JFormattedTextField with a java.util.Date (JDatePickerImpl 1.3.4)

Tags: java, swing, date, datepicker

I tried different ways but still I can't get the Java `util.Date` instance returned by a method I created to display on my `JDatePicker's` `JFormattedText`

I printed the value of `util.Date` I am getting which is **2018-01-01**

Let's call the variable `dateStart` which holds the value **2018-01-01**

When I tried to do

```
jDatePickerImpl.getJFormattedTextField().setText(dateStart+"");
```

it displays **2018-01-01** on the `JFormattedTextField` which is okay.

But the problem is, as soon as I click on the `JDatePickerImpl` component, I get an `exception` error

[image]

```
AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.util.Calendar
    at utility.date.DateLabelFormatter.valueToString(DateLabelFormatter.java:26)
```

So I thought maybe I could use the `setDate(int,int,int)` method of it's `JDatePanelImpl` instance.

```
jDatePanelImpl.getModel().setDate(getYear(utilDate),getMonth(utilDate),getDay(utilDate));

    private int getYear(Date date) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);    
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        return year;
    }

    private int getMonth(Date date) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        return month;
    }

    private int getDay(Date date) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return day;
    }
```

But when I do that, I only get a blank or empty `JFormattedTextField`

I'm able to display the date in string format but it doesn't solve the problem because as soon as I click the `JDatePicker` component, I get an exception error.

This is the first time I tried to use the `JDatePicker` library and I just don't know what to do next.

By the way, the `util.Date` object I'm trying to set on the `JFormattedTextField` is a date from a database `Resultset` but I've converted it to `util.Date` format which is why I was able to print out it's value.

Thank you.

Comment: Any reason why in your code you are using the long outdated `Date` and `Calendar`classes? [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) is so much nicer to work with. I recommend you get the date as `LocalDate` from the database. If you need to pass a `Date` or `Calendar` to the date picker library, only convert just before doing that.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thank you. I haven't checked those Java 8 API for handling dates. This is the first time I created a project with many date inputs and outputs which led me to using JDatePicker1.3.4. Haven't tried it in the past.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same issue. But this solved my issue

set "setSelected(true)" after you set the date

```
jDatePanelImpl.getModel().setDate(getYear(utilDate),getMonth(utilDate),getDay(utilDate));

jDatePanelImpl.getModel().setSelected(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the model of `JDatePicker` as `DateModel<Calendar>` and set the value as below:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);
DateModel<Calendar> dateModel = (DateModel<Calendar>) datePicker.getModel();
dateModel.setValue(calendar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your stacktrace shows you what is wrong and where it is wrong.

You're passing a java.util.Date to the method DateLabelFormatter.valueToString() (line 26) which takes a Calendar. A Date cannot be converted to a Calendar in runtime, which causes the error when the method is called.

Either pass a Calendar to the method or change the method to take a Date instead.